# CSS Button Doesn't Look the Same on IOS

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS code and it works fine on android and PC Browser but not Iphone

```
.button{
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #4A5D88 ;
    padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.button:hover{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

this is how it works [every](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUS1w.jpg) where but not on [Iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKFRO.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem - the linear gradient or the size? Please be more clear about the "not working" state

Comment: @biberman my problem that it doesn't work the same while i want it to look like the same

Comment: @DavidRaouf What exactly isn't the same?

Comment: @AB7zz the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line and it should work normally.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: thank you, dose that work as well with list tag?